# Shell do Python e Django

Tags: python, django, shell

Sei que para abrir o shell interativo do Python, simplesmente executamos no terminal do sistema operacional:

```
python
```

Mas com o Django instalado, também é possível abrir o shell usando o comando:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Existe alguma diferença entre as duas maneiras de invocar o interpretador Python?

Comment: Pelo que eu saiba, o shell do Django é só uma shell Python pronta para interagir com seu ambiente Django. Creio que essa documentação possa ajudar: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao abrir o shell usando `python manage.py shell`, dentro do diretório do seu projeto Django, será configurado o ambiente para que seja possível a interação com os objetos do seu código-fonte a partir do shell do Python.

É possível fazer esta configuração de ambiente manualmente abrindo o shell com `python`, importar o pacote do Django e em seguida configurar a variável de ambiente `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` para o `settings.py` do seu projeto.

Usar `python manage.py shell` é apenas uma maneira que o Django oferece para  facilitar esta configuração do ambiente do seu projeto no shell do Python.

Answer (score 1):

Quando voce abre o python shell "puro" voce tem disponível apenas os pacotes disponíveis na sua env. Ao abrir via manage.py, voce tem disponível, no shell, toda a configuração e objetos do seu projeto, podendo, por exemplo, importar uma classe de qualquer model de qualquer app definida no projeto, fazer CRUD (através dessas classes/models), executar comandos do manager, executar rotinas de testes, e por ai vai.... :-)